# PHP truncate mb_substr is giving different length results

Tags: php, utf-8, truncate

I'm using this function to truncate some titles to a specific length:

```
function truncateUTF8($str, $length, $breakWords = TRUE, $append = '...') {
    $strLength = mb_strlen($str);
    if ($strLength <= $length) {
       return $str;
    }
    if (!$breakWords) {
       while ($length < $strLength AND preg_match('/^\pL$/', mb_substr($str, $length, 1))) {
         $length++;
       }
    }
    return rtrim(mb_substr($str, 0, $length)) . $append;
}
```

Calling:

```
echo truncateUTF8($str,94);
```

Will return different string lenghts on UTF8 strings, take a look at these strings:

**ORIGINAL STR**
Mais de 100 carcaças de aviões de empresas falidas serão retiradas de aeroportos até o fim do ano
**// 98 chars**

**TRUNCATED STR**
Mais de 100 carcaças de aviões de empresas falidas serão retiradas de aeroportos até o fim do...
**// 94 chars** - ok

**ORIGINAL STR**
Notícias Transbrasil – 28 – MP pode atuar em ações falimentares em que a lei não determina sua intervenção (STJ)
**// 113 chars**

**TRUNCATED STR**
Notícias Transbrasil – 28 – MP pode atuar em ações falimentares em que a lei não d...
**// 83 chars**

What's going on here? Why's the second str truncated at 83 chars instead of 94 chars, like the first str?

Thanks.

Comment: I think because its because some UTF8 characters consists of two or three UNICODE entities, these differences might be the reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
function truncateUTF8($str, $length, $breakWords = TRUE, $append = '...') {
    $strLength = mb_strlen($str);
    if ($strLength <= $length)
       return $str;
    return preg_replace('/(.{' . $length . '}).*/u', '$1' .  $append, $str);
}
```

Comment: Looks like it works, but if the break character has punctuation like "ã", this would render this char as a decoding error (? char)

Comment: @AntonioMax I do not quite understand you. Can you give me an example what you meant?

Comment: If the final word thats going to be breaked is "não" and it breaks on the "nã" (so we have "nã..." as the end of the str), your function is rendering n?... istead of nã...

Comment: Oops, Sorry, I forgot to add the modifier "u", like this '/(.{' . $length . '}).*/u' Now everything will be fine :)

Comment: Even better replace preg_replace to mb_substr
`return mb_substr($str, 0, $length, 'UTF-8') . $append;`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. But for some reason, titles that have " - " on it, still gives max of 83 characters (without the ...) instead of 94 chars (the length I defined)

Comment: @AntonioMax Hmm.. Again I not quite understand you. See, I wrote in function
`return mb_substr($str, 0, $length, 'UTF-8') . $append;`

We have string
`$str = '$str = 'Notícias Transbrasil – 28 – MP pode atuar em ações falimentares em que a lei não determina sua intervenção';'`
this is 106 chars. If I write
`echo truncateUTF8($str,94);`
I will `Notícias Transbrasil – 28 – MP pode atuar em ações falimentares em que a lei não determina sua...` this is 94 chars (without ...).
All correct. Or am I not understood you ?

Comment: You're damn right!! I just copied the function to a blank php file and voilá, it works just like it should. I'm using this function inside wordpress and for some reason, I get the 83 chars when a title has " - " on it. The function is inside the wordpress functions.php unchanged. I have no idea why I get the 83 chars :| so weird!!

Comment: Ok, now that I've found that wordpress is somehow changing the titles I have tried `the_title_attribute()` (instead of `the_title()`) and it didn't work too. Then using raw `$post->post_title` I got the correct string length. Thank you very much for all your help Wiston!